# How can I use Fubini's Theorem here?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, fubini-tonelli-theorems

**Exercise:**

> If $F$ is a continuous distribution function on $(\mathbb R, \mathscr B, \mu_{\mathcal L})$ with distribution $\mu_F$, use Fubini's theorem to show that
>
> 1. $\int_{\mathbb R} F(x) \, d\mu_F(x) = \frac{1}{2}$
> 2. if $X_1, X_2$ are i.i.d random variables with common distribution $F$, then $P(\{X_1 \leq X_2 \}) = 1/2$ and $\text E(F(X_1)) = 1/2$.

**My Attempt:**

I don't really understand bs_math's answer so I have been trying to write my own. I just deleted an attempt here that was (I think) completely nonsensical. I am working on another attempt.

For example, I don't understand what's going on in line 4 of bs_math's answer.

Comment: Hint: Write $F(x)$ in terms of $\mu_F$

Comment: @bs_math I have a case-by-case definition stating that

\begin{align*}
F(x) =
\begin{cases}
\mu((0, x]) \text{ if } x > 0\\
0 \text{ if } x = 0\\
-\mu((x, 0]) \text{ if } x < 0.
\end{cases}
\end{align*} You think this leads to Fubini's theorem?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken that would give me two integrals that look something like $\int \mu_F\big((0, x] \big) \, d\mu_f$, and I am not sure what the integral of a measure with respect to that same measure is.

Comment: Try $\mu((0, x]) = \int_{-\infty}^x 1 d\mu_F(x)$

Comment: @bs_math Thanks. I need to try to remember how the measure relates to an improper Riemann integral now.

Comment: If you know the Lebesgue integral, I recommend that one

Comment: @bs_math I have used the Lebesgue integral but it looks like I need to think more about how to represent the cases in the defintion of $F(x)$, e.g. $\mu_F((0, x])$, in terms of a Lebesgue integral. I'm trying to remember if I've seen anything about this somewhere.

Comment: I know about measures induced by integrals of measurable functions, but I think those functions need to be non-negative, and I don't think $F$ is required to be non-negative.

Answer (score 5):

The distribution function is generally defined as
$$ F: x \mapsto \mu_F((-\infty, x]), $$
see [Wikpedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function). The OP relies on another definition stating that
$$ \tilde{F}(x) = \begin{cases}
\mu_F((0, x], & x > 0, \\
0, &x = 0, \\
- \mu_F((-x, 0], &x < 0.
\end{cases}
$$
Then we have $\tilde{F} = F + c$ for the constant summand $c = - \mu_F((-\infty, 0])$. I have never seen this as a definition of the distribution function. The fact that one can show the claim
$$ \int_\mathbb{R} F(x) \, d\mu_F(x) = \frac{1}{2} \tag{1} $$
for $F$ shows that $(1)$ is actually false as soon as $c \neq 0$. So I assume there is a misunderstanding regarding the intended definition of $F$.

Now, in order to show $(1)$ use that by the very definition of the Lebesgue integral it is
$$ F(x) = \mu((-\infty, x]) = \int_\mathbb{R} 1_{(-\infty, x]}(y) \, d\mu_F(y).$$
Then, consider the following transformations:
\begin{align}
\int_\mathbb{R} F(x) d\mu_F(x) 
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_\mathbb{R} 1_{(-\infty, x]}(y) \, d\mu_F(y)  \, d\mu_F(x) \\
&= \int_\mathbb{R} \int_\mathbb{R} 1_{(-\infty, x]}(y) \, d\mu_F(x) \, d\mu_F(y) \\
&= \int_\mathbb{R} \int_{\mathbb{R}} 1_{[y, \infty)}(x) \, d \mu_F(x) \, d\mu_F(y) \\
&= \int_\mathbb{R} 1 - F(y) \, d\mu_F(y) \\
&= 1 - \int_\mathbb{R} F(x) \, d \mu_F(x), \tag{2}
\end{align}
where we use Fubinis's theorem in the second line. To get from the second to the third line we observe for every $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$
$$ 1_{(-\infty, x]}(y) = 1 \Leftrightarrow y \leq x \Leftrightarrow 1_{[y, \infty)}(x) = 1. $$
In the fourth line we use that for fixed $y$ one has
\begin{align*}
\int_\mathbb{R} 1_{[y, \infty)}(x) \, d \mu_F(x)
&= \int_\mathbb{R} 1 - 1_{(-\infty, y)}(x) \, d\mu_F(x) \\
&= 1 - \int_\mathbb{R} 1_{(-\infty, y)}(x) \, d\mu_F(x) \\
&= 1 - \lim_{h \searrow 0} \int_\mathbb{R} 1_{(-\infty, y - h]}(x) \, d\mu_F(x) \\
&= 1 - \lim_{h \searrow 0} F(y-h) \\
&= 1 - F(y),
\end{align*}
where we use Beppo-Levi's theorem in the third line.

The claim $(1)$ follows immediately from $(2)$ by rearranging terms.

Here all intgrals are to be understood as Lebesgue integrals.

Comment: If you have time I'd appreciate an explanation for what you've written. I don't understand your first line. What about the three cases for $F$? Can the inner integral on the first line be written as a Lebesgue integral? Why is it okay to rewrite the indicator function on line 4? How does line 5 follow from line 4 without a density in the integrand? Thanks.